# Prevent "Google password Required" notification (Mac OS X)

Tags: email, notifications, google

I know in Systems Preferences I can delete the Google account which will stop the notifications. However, I'd like to keep this account and simply stop being notified to enter my password. I deactivated this account on Google so I no longer have my password. I want to keep this account on my Mac because it has email I still want to see.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try unchecking "Include when automatically checking for new messages"

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, I think this works. I'll accept this answer as soon as I know for sure.

Comment: dang, didn't work :(

Comment: *D'oh!*  I did think of an alternative - move the entire contents to a user folder then just disable the account. I'll post as an alternative answer if it does work, but I've nothing here I can really test it on.

Comment: I disabled the account so it no longer shows up in Apple Mail. That doesn't delete the mail which is stored locally in  `~/users/{your-username}/Library/Mail`. That should be good enough. Though, if I want to search my email I have to go in that folder every time and open the mailbox. Oh well, probably won't do that often, if ever.  We'll see. Thanks for your help!